# Determine which file system a file or directory is located in Linux

Tags: python

I'm trying to find file or directory real path and which file system it is located in Linux. For example, I have a symbol link:

```
[felixc@apphost ~]$ df -k
Filesystem           1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_apphost-lv_root
                      15350768  3442620  11121716  24% /
tmpfs                  1962136       16   1962120   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1               487652    79197    382855  18% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_apphost-lv_home
                      15351248  1558304  13006516  11% /home
/dev/mapper/vg_apphost-lvdata2
                      67608152 14865428  49301676  24% /data2

[felixc@apphost ~]$ ls -l /usr/local
total 44
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Jun 14 10:06 bin
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Sep 23  2011 etc
...
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   14 Dec 29  2015 apphome -> /data2/apphome
```

But when I ran following code:

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: os.path.abspath('/usr/local/apphome/ansible-hosts')
Out[2]: '/usr/local/apphome/ansible-hosts'
I was expecting: /data2/apphome/ansible-hosts
```

How can I find the ansible-hosts is located in /data2? I can see Linux command '*df filename*' can find it out. Is there any python way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `os.path.realpath` gives the terminus of a chain of symlink hops.
- `os.path.abspath` makes relative paths absolute, but it may not name the terminus.
- `os.readlink` finds the nearest symlink hop

Therefore, use `os.path.realpath('/usr/local/apphome/ansible-hosts')`.